# X11 "eyedropper" application to inspect pixel color?

Tags: x11, colors, display

Is there an application I can use to obtain the RGB values of a particular pixel on the screen?  I'm thinking something similar to paint programs where you can use an "eyedropper" to sample a color.

Comment: I found this - https://github.com/Ancurio/colorpicker.

Comment: Particular as in x,y for specified values of x,y? Or particular as in select visually with a mouse (or other pointing device)?

Comment: Another example - https://blog.wizardsoftheweb.pro/quickly-detect-cursor-position-and-color/.

Comment: Shows some methods as well - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22099801/shell-command-to-get-color-under-mouse-cursor-xorg

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find [Gpick](http://www.gpick.org/) (package name gpick) and [gcolor2](http://gcolor2.sourceforge.net/) in many repositories.

Comment: Note well: gpic and gpick are different!